# How to display a custom button to add a product to the WooCommerce cart?

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I need to make a lot of custom buttons that would add products to the cart:

```html
<button type="button" class="button add_to_cart" data-product_id="998" data-quantity="1">
  Add to cart
</button>
```

The method with the link is very bad and does not work correctly:
`https://site-link/?add-to-cart=998&quantity=1`

I tried many other options, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple product type, To display an add to cart button, there are multiple ways.

1. Using an Ajax add to cart button:

   ```
   <a href="#" class="button add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="998" data-quantity="1" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
   ```
2. Using POST method with a submit button that requires a surrounding form:

   ```
   <form class="cart-custom" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" class="qty" name="quantity" value="1">
       <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="998" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Add to cart</button>
   </form>
   ```
3. Using GET method with a linked button (but it displays the query string in the URL):

   ```
   <a href="?add-to-cart=998&quantity=1" class="button add_to_cart_button" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
   ```